# Adding 1 day to selective time period of date column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a table where it has a column 'Date', 'Time', 'Costs'.

I want to select rows where the time is greater than 12:00:00, then add 1 day to 'Date' column of the selected rows.

How should I go about in doing it?

So far I have:

```
df[df['Time']>'12:00:00']['Date'] = df[df['Time']>'12:00:00']['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]') + timedelta(days=1)
```

I am a beginner in learning coding and any suggestions would be really helpful! Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be related to pandas so you should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: What type is your Time column?

Comment: Thanks I've made the updates on tags. The datatype is Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) first for column `Date` if not datetimes, then convert column `Time` to string if possible `python time`s, convert to datetimes and get `hours` by [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html), compare and add `1` day by condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2015-01-02','2016-05-08'],
                   'Time':['10:00:00','15:00:00']})

print (df)
         Date      Time
0  2015-01-02  10:00:00
1  2016-05-08  15:00:00

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
mask = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].astype(str)).dt.hour > 12
df.loc[mask, 'Date'] += pd.Timedelta(days=1)
print (df)
        Date      Time
0 2015-01-02  10:00:00
1 2016-05-09  15:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I ran:
from datetime import timedelta
df.loc[df['Time'] > '12:00:00','Date'] = df.loc[df['Time'] > '12:00:00','Date'].astype('datetime64') + timedelta(days=1)